# Limit of an integral on [0,1]

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

I need to prove a limit on a closed interval $[0,1]$.

$f$ is integrable.

$$\lim_{n\to \infty}\int_0^1 x^n f(x) \, dx=0$$

Where should I start from?

Comment: What do you know about $x^n$ on the interval $[0, 1]$?

Comment: By integral, you mean Lebesgue integrable or Riemann integrable?

Comment: I believe it should be Lebesgue, although the problem doesn't specify.

Answer (score 4):

If by "integrable" you mean Riemann integrable, then an integrable function must be bounded, and so
$$\left|\int\limits_{0}^{1}{x^nf(x)\text{ d}x}\right|\le\left(\max\limits_{x\in[0,1]}{|f(x)|}\right)\int\limits_{0}^{1}{x^n\text{ d}x}. $$
Note that $\int\limits_{0}^{1}{x^n\text{ d}x} = \frac{1}{n+1}$.

If by "integrable" you mean Lebesgue integrable, then the functions $f_n(x) = x^nf(x)$ converges pointwise to zero almost everywhere, and $|f_n(x)|\le|f(x)|$ everywhere, so we can apply the Dominated Convergence Theorem.

Answer (score 2):

I assume you mean $f\in L^1(0,1)$. Note $C[0,1]$ is dense in $L^1(0,1)$ under $L^1$ norm, so it suffices to prove it with $f\in C[0,1]$ and then pass to limit (Please see the comments for details).

Given $f\in C[0,1]$, by uniformly continuous, for any $\epsilon>0$, you can find a step function $g$, $0\le f(x)-g(x)\le \epsilon$ for all $x\in[0,1]$, so it suffices to prove it for step functions and then pass to limit.

Then by linearity of integral, it suffices to prove it for $f=1_{[a,b]}$, which is easy by simple calculation.

Comment: More explicitly: you are approximating the given function $f$ with a sequence $f_m$ such that $f_m\to f$ in some sense. You have established that for any fixed $m$ you have $\lim_{n\to \infty} \int x^n f_m(x)\, dx=0$. Now you have to let $m$ go to infinity. How can you justify that $\lim_{n\to \infty} \lim_{m\to \infty} \int x^nf_m(x)\, dx=0$?

Comment: @GiuseppeNegro Given $\epsilon>0$, we find $g$ such that $|g-f|_{L^1}<\frac{\epsilon}{2}$ . Then we prove $\exists N$ such that $\forall n\ge N$, we have $|\int x^n g|<\frac{\epsilon}{2}$. Hence $\forall n\ge N$, $|\int x^n f|\le |\int x^n f-\int x^n g|+|\int x^n g|\le \int |f-g|+|\int x^n g|<\epsilon$, which gives the desired convergence.

Comment: @GiuseppeNegro Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Since $f$ is integrable, it is finite almost everywhere. Then $x^n\,f(x)$ converges to $0$ almost everywhere in$[0,1]$. Moreover $|x^n\,f(x)|\le|f(x)|$ for all $x\in[0,1]$. The result follows now from the Dominated Convergence Theorem.